# WPF Datagrid Column Visibility not working with MultiBinding

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am trying to control the visibility of a DataGridTextColumn using two Boolean values. One of the values is being set by a combo box and I am able to see in the debugger that Boolean values are being properly handled by the booleanAllTrueConverter.

My problem is that the converter value being returned has no effect on the column visibility. The column is always visible even when FALSE is returned from the converter.

I would certainly appreciate any ideas that are offered.

Thanks.

```
<DataGrid 
    Name="myDataGrid" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ZZZZ}}"  
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    IsReadOnly="True" 
    KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None"
    >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding SomeItems}" >
            <DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource booleanAllTrueConverter}">
                    <Binding 
                        Source="{StaticResource ProxyElement}" 
                        Path="DataContext.IsBlahVisible" 
                        Mode="TwoWay" 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
                        />
                    <Binding 
                        Source="{StaticResource ProxyElement}" 
                        Path="DataContext.AreColumnsVisible" 
                        Mode="TwoWay" 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"
                        />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataGridTextColumn.Visibility>
            <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <local:ComboBox 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Width="22" 
                            Height="36" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SomeItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                            SelectedItems="{Binding DataContext.SelectedSomeItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                            ></local:ComboBox>
                        <TextBlock 
                            Text="SomeItems" 
                            Grid.Column="1" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                            Height="16" 
                            Margin="0,3" 
                            Width="37" 
                            />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Visibility isn't boolean. It's an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return either `Visibility.Visible` instead of `true` or return `Visibility.Collapsed` instead of `false` from `booleanAllTrueConverter`

Comment: OK. I'll try that out. Thanks for the quick answer. I hope to approve your answer soon.

Comment: Bingo. I created a new converter that returns Visibility.Visible if all the inputs are true.    Thanks for your help.